# Prove $f(x)$ is irreducible and its roots are real.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $3$ and let $E$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb Q$. Show that if $G(E/\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/\mathbb 3\mathbb Z$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible and its roots are all real. Is my proof correct, and is there a shorter way?

My thoughts so far are as follows: Since each of the roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ of $f(x)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, we know that $E = \mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ has characteristic $0$, it must be perfect and thus $E$ is a separable extension of $\mathbb Q$. Thus, $|G(E/\mathbb Q)| = [E:\mathbb Q] = \{E:\mathbb Q \} = 3.$ The fact that $E$ is a finite separable extension implies that it is a simple extension of $\mathbb Q$, so $\exists \alpha\in E: E = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$. We also know that the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$ has degree $3$.

If $f(x)$ were reducible over $\mathbb Q$, then it would factor into a linear and quadratic factor. If this quadratic factor were irreducible, then $[E:\mathbb Q]$ would be divisible by $2$, a contradiction. But if it were reducible, then $[E:\mathbb Q] = 1$, another contradiction. Thus, $f(x)$ must be irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

$f(x)$ either has $3$ real roots, or $1$ real root and a pair of complex conjugate roots. Assume the latter case is true and suppose without loss of generality that one of the non-real roots is $\alpha_1$. Since $[\mathbb Q(\alpha_1):\mathbb Q] = 3$ and $\mathbb Q(\alpha_1)\subseteq E$, we see that $E = \mathbb Q(\alpha_1)$. So then any $\sigma \in G(E/\mathbb Q)$ is completely determined by $\sigma(\alpha_1)$, which can be $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,$ or $\alpha_3$.

Suppose without loss of generality that the complex conjugate of $\alpha_1$ is $\alpha_2$, and let $\sigma_2\in G(E/\mathbb Q)$ send $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_2$. Now since $G(E/\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, we should have that $\sigma_2 \circ \sigma_2 (\alpha_1) = \alpha_3$. But since $\sigma_2$ matches up with the automorphism of $E$ defined by complex conjugation, we have that $\sigma_2 \circ \sigma_2 (\alpha_1) = \alpha_1$, a contradiction. We conclude that $f(x)$ has $3$ real roots.

Comment: Easier argument: if $f$ did not have all real roots, then complex conjugation is always an element of $G(E/\mathbb{Q})$, and it has order $2$.  We cannot have a subgroup of order $2$ inside of a group of order $3$.